# How to find out which specflow step is getting executed while debugging on visual studio console

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, nunit, specflow, specrun

I'm using visual studio 2015 and specflow . All looks good but out of curiosity how can i see which step is getting debugged and on which step i'm on . if i run the test with Nunit provider then it is showing the all the steps information but while debug it is not showing . Any suggestion?

Comment: like Alexandru Marculescu's suggestion, using the ReSharper which runs unit tests in the Unit Test Sessions window would be a nice workaround, could you get useful information?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to gather that information by either going through the call stack (which should eventually lead to an actual step decorated with an attribute), or by looking over the output in the Unit Test Sessions tab:

[image: Unit Test Sessions tab]

Answer (score 0):

If you change on the call stack window to your feature file, you should see the current step

[image]